# How to only display certain test categories with SpecFlow and Rider?

Tags: mstest, specflow, rider

How do you only display unit tests with a certain category in Rider?

In Visual Studio I would deselect all and then select the category I want...

[image]

I can't seem to do this in Rider. The best I can do is change the `Group By` to `Categories` and type the name of the category, however it still displays other categories that exist with the category you are filtering on....

[image]

Which is showing the 5 tags separately for the following test, even though I only want the `Chromium` tag

```
@tc:33656
@Pixel_5
@iPhone_11
@Chromium
@DeletePost
#------------------------------------------------
Scenario: Add a post to a regular customer
Login as a regular Boomin customer and add a post
via My Playground
```